# Delphi - Panel & Button Click Effect

Tags: delphi

I have a CheckBox that shows and hides a Panel that has a Button & two TEdits (for entering an IP address & its port).

[image: screenshot]

The problem is the Button has no effect, it stays gray, also the Panel still shows. I tried different methods, e.g. `ModalResult := mrOk;`, which didn't change anything.

Here is my code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked = True then begin
Panel1.Visible := True;
  end
    else
  if CheckBox1.Checked = False then begin
Panel1.Visible := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Button1: TButton;
begin
Button1 := Sender as TButton;
ShowMessage(Button1.Caption + ' Changes');
end;

end.
```

Comment: How do you show Form1? Is it called from another form?

Comment: The checkbox and the panel is in Form1. Thanks.

Comment: If you showed the form with `Form1.ShowModal` then `ModalResult := mrOk;` in Button1Click should work.  Otherwise just call `Close;`

Comment: What is the actual problem? That the CheckBox does not show/hide the Panel correctly? Or that the Button does not display the popup message (or close the Form)? Make sure your `OnClick` events are actually assigned. If you are still having a problem, please show the content of the actual DFM.

Comment: Why would you expect the Panel to hide after clicking the button?  All you're doing is calling ShowMessage.

Comment: @Jason: that's right. can you give me an example code ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question..

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure Showpanel(AShow: boolean);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Showpanel(AShow: boolean);
begin
  Checkbox1.checked := AShow;
  Panel1.Visible := AShow; 
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowPanel(false);  
end;

procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.visible := Checkbox1.Checked;   
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Showmessage(Button1.Caption + ' Changes');
end;



end.
```

Comment: Its work so beautifully. But can you provide a solution, so that the checkbox stays checked after the button being clicked ? Thanks so much, anyway..!

Comment: @RzV Remove `Showpanel(false);` from the button click event method?

Comment: John, it doesn't work. Removing the `Showpanel(false);` making the Panel always visible. Thank you!

Comment: I removed showpanel(false) from button1click @RzV.  Didn't know you wanted the panel and checkbox settings to persist...